# Code formatting in comments overflows into related questions

Tags: bug, comments, design, mobile-web

iPhone 6 Plus
iOS 9.2.1
Chrome & safari browsers

When in 'full site' mode, large amounts of code formatted in comments spills into the related questions section.

Can be replicated on chrome and safari browsers (haven't got anymore to test on).

[Why is this long overflowing to -1, instead of the minimum value for the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650048/why-is-this-long-overflowing-to-1-instead-of-the-minimum-value-for-the-type?rq=1) Is an example.

Not the end of the world but guessing it's not intended?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can recreate on desktop by toggling device mode in the Chrome dev tools